# Union between T and void throws incompatible error

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have the follow representation of the issue:

```js
class Message {
    value: string;
}

type Class = { new (...args: any[]): any };

function Test<T extends Class>(type?: T) {
    return (
        target: object,
        key: string | symbol,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<
        (...args: any[]) => InstanceType<T> | void
    > | void => {
    };
}

class Controller {
    @Test()
    test(): void { }

    @Test(Message)
    test2(): Message {
        return {
            value: 'test2'
        }
    }

}
```

The `@Test(Message)` method decorator for `test2` has the following error:
`Type '(...args: any[]) => void | Message' is not assignable to type '() => Message'.`

The only solution I found is to change `test2` return type to `Message | void`, but there is no other solution to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following code is working fine:

```js
class Message {
    value: string;
}

type Class = { new (...args: any[]): any };

function Test<T extends Class, U extends (...args: any[]) => InstanceType<T>>(
    type?: T
) {
    return (
        target: object,
        key: string | symbol,
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<U>
    ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<U> | void => {
        return descriptor;
    };
}

class Controller {
    @Test()
    test(): void {}

    @Test(Message)
    test2(): Message {
        return {
            value: 'test2'
        };
    }
}
```